# Material question - how to make this reflective?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, light

Ok, I have a diffuse/emissive material applied to the large blue cube below:

[image]

This is created with these nodeS:

[image]

Ive tried adding in some sort of glossy node but am not versed with in depth making materials- I need the large blue glowing cube to also REFLECT the glowing things/lights around it (i.e. the emissive ring)

I need it to have some reflection like the black cubes do. How can I integrate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the emissive shader doesn't really work well with the glossy. What I think is happening is the emissive texture is taking all of the light that is reflecting into the camera. It is basically bleaching out the ability for the light to reflect and is making it difficult if not impossible to see the small amounts of light reflecting off. to fix this, I recommend that you basically reduce the amount of emissive compared to the glossy so that it's not for the lack of a better word overshadowed. I did a test render here. It appears to work but it might not be exactly what we're looking for

[image: Reflective/emissive material]

Comment: We will also expect any emissive object, which is not a lamp, to be translucent, because we expect the light source to be inside of it. And translucent but not transparent objects will be very rough on the surface and subsurface, which would appear extremely diffuse. So next to a difference in intensity, which you fixed, the combination of glossy and emissive simply doesn't correlate with our vieweing experience and expectations.